# Is there a more concise way to get value from EXEC sp_configure into a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
DECLARE @options TABLE
    (
        name nvarchar(max),
        minimum int,
        maximum int,
        config_value int,
        run_value int
    )
    -- Gets the advanced options enabled flag and sets @value accordingly
    INSERT INTO @options EXEC sp_configure @configname='show advanced options'
    DECLARE @value AS BIT = 0
    SELECT @value = config_value FROM @options
```

This is working, but I feel like declaring a variable table just to hold the result of sp_configure to save a single value from it is overkill.  Is there a more concise way to do this?  All I want to do is get the current value of the 'show advanced options' into a variable.  I am using Microsoft SQL for this query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `sys.configurations` object:

```
SELECT [value]
FROM sys.configurations
WHERE [name] = N'show advanced options'
```

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of sys.configurations.